# vimrc function to search filename using literal `*` in a file which has list of all project filenames with absolute path

Tags: vim, grep

I have a large file called index.txt which has all absolute path of all files listed say,

```
common/mac_get.c
common/addr/addr_main_set_clear_config.c
common/addr/mac/mac_load_done.c
```

Need to write vimrc function to search only last word in each line of  index.txt with delimiter as / (i.e search only basename ) and not match for foldername also it should accept * as a part of argument in search.

say If I pass argument `mac*.c` then It should search file starting with mac  & ending with .c then return results as,

```
common/mac_get.c
common/addr/mac/mac_load_done.c
```

say If I pass argument `mac*done.c` then It should search file starting with mac  and ending with done.c then return results as,

```
common/addr/mac/mac_load_done.c
```

say If I pass argument `*main*.c` or `*main*set*.c` then It should return results as,

```
common/addr/addr_main_set_clear_config.c
```

This is what I've tried so far :

```
function! searchFname(fname)
   execute "silent! grep!" a:fname "~/index.txt"
endfunction

command! -nargs=* Fname call SearchFname('<args>')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure the input will always with `.c` part? could it be something like `*o*`? Also the `return results....` how do you want to get the returned results? in a list? just print it out? or in a new buffer? in qf?

Comment: @Kent Input always end with `.c` or `.h` or .`cpp` part. Return results means just store into l:file and print l:file with echom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` uses `*` as a quantifier that matches the preceding element zero or more times, but you're requiring to use it as a wildcard that matches any characters.

Even though `grep` doesn't use wildcards, you can build equivalent regular expressions, e.g:

- `*` is equivalent to `.*`
- `?` is equivalent to `.`

To match only filenames (excluding the path), it's necessary to replace `.` with `[^/]` as follows:

```
function! SearchFname(fname)
    execute 'silent! grep! "^\(.*\/\)\?' . substitute(substitute(substitute(a:fname,'\*','[^/]*','g'),'\.','\\.','g'),'?','[^/]','g') . '$"' "~/index.txt"
endfunction

command! -nargs=* Fname call SearchFname('<args>')
```

But `grep`'s output will still be shown on the terminal Vim was started up. To get rid of it you can use the `:vimgrep` command instead, but you need to use a pattern as in Vim search (see [`:help :vimgrep`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Avimgrep) for details):

```
function! SearchFname(fname)
    execute 'silent! vimgrep /^\(.*\/\)\?' . substitute(substitute(substitute(a:fname,'\*','[^\/]*','g'),'\.','\.','g'),'?','[^\/]','g') . "$/j" "~/index.txt"
endfunction

command! -nargs=* Fname call SearchFname('<args>')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the wonderful answer. Just want to add the serial number to the output of above grep results. I found that the if I pipe result with `| nl` then it print line numbers also but in this case it giving error `
E492: Not an editor command:  nl  /dev/null` Please let me know how to use it here

Comment: With the `:grep!` command, Vim already executes `grep` with the `-n` option (prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file) and `grep` outputs the intended result but Vim parses it to create a quickfix list (See [`:help 30.1`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_30.txt.html#30.1) and [`:help quickfix.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#quickfix.txt)).

Comment: By the way, Vim uses `|` to separate two commands on the same line and that's why it said `E492: ...` (`nl` is not a Vim command). See [`:help getqflist()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getqflist%28%29) to know how to get such information.

Comment: You always provide best solution and good guidance. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: After calling searchFname() function if I quit vim then all results are getting display on terminal / bash window also. redraw! is not working here.(version is `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3` `echo $TERM` showing `xterm` but `Ctrl+L` is working and clearing screen.) How to run this command in background to avoid seeing result on bash window ? So that It shouldn't even get seen it after scrolling terminal / bash window. I am using the getqflist() function after doing grep in function so hope solution will not affect the usage of getqflist() just after grep.

Comment: As for `:redraw!` , it works in Vim's session, not on the terminal.