# vim script : How to stop grep from displaying output on terminal after quitting Vim editor.

Tags: vim, grep

I have following command in vim script,

```
function! SearchFname(fname)
execute "silent! grep!" a:fname "~/Index.files"
let l:file = getqflist()
for l:item in l:file
    execute 'vsplit' l:item["text"]
endfor
endfunction
command! -nargs=* Mysplit call SearchFname('<args>')
```

After executing Mysplit if I quit vim then grep result is getting display on terminal / bash window. How to run `grep` command in background to avoid seeing result on bash window ?
So that I shouldn't even seen it after scrolling terminal / bash window. I am using the `getqflist()` function after grep in function so hope solution will not affect the usage of `getqflist()`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `system()` or `systemlist()` to get the output of an external command into a variable without filling the screen:

```
let myvar = system("grep foo somefile.txt")
```

But I don't get why you use `grep` and `getqflist()` at all. Here is a much simpler alternative:

```
function! SearchFname(fname)
    let files = filter(readfile("~/Index.files"), 'v:value =~ a:fname')
    for file in files
        execute 'vsplit' file
    endfor
endfunction
```

--- EDIT ---

If you need to restrict the matches to filenames, try this version instead:

```
function! SearchFname(fname)
    let files = filter(readfile("~/Index.files"), 'fnamemodify(v:val, ":t") =~ a:fname')
    for file in files
        execute 'vsplit' file
    endfor
endfunction
```

If you absolutely want to use globs instead of proper Vim patterns, try this version:

```
function! SearchFname(fname)
    let pat = substitute(a:fname, "\*", ".*", "g")
    let files = filter(readfile("~/Index.files"), 'fnamemodify(v:val, ":t") =~ pat')
    for file in files
        execute 'vsplit' file
    endfor
endfunction
```

Comment: Actually, Index.files files contain the absolute path for all the files of project and I am serching a:fname only in filename and it can use the literal '*' in a:fname to search filenames.
For this I am using `execute "silent! grep!" substitute(substitute(substitute(a:fname,'\*','[^/]*','g'),'\.','\\\\.','g'),'?','[^/]','g') . "$" ~/Index.files`
how to do same with your approach.  My earlier question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878144/vimrc-function-to-search-filename-using-literal-in-a-file-which-has-list-of/36955846?noredirect=1#comment61711091_36955846]

Comment: `=~` treats `a:fname:` as a regular expression so it will find `a:fname` in `file` no matter how long/complex `file` is. If you want to make sure only filenames are used you can use this expression: 'fnamemodify(v:val, ":t") =~ a:fname'.

Comment: I passed fname as `mac_*_main.c`, it's should match in `~/Index.files` to  `mac_cfg_main.c` but value for variable `files` is coming as `[ ]` instead of `mac_cfg_main.c`

Comment: Could you add a sample `Index.files` to your question?

Comment: `common/mac_get.c`
    `common/addr/addr_main_set_clear_config.c`
    `common/addr/mac/mac_load_done.c`
    `common/addr/mac/config/src/mac_cfg_main.c`

[each path on new line in Index.files]

Comment: I used your suggested globs version.  After your edit if I pass fname as `*_cfg_*.c` then it giving relevant result along with other irrrelevant results like `mac_cfg_main.c`, `mac_cfg_main.h`  and `mac_cfg_set.xml` Ideally It should grep only c files here as our search string `*_cfg_*.c` ends with `*.c` here.

Comment: Well, you'll need to escape a bunch of meta-characters. `*` --> `.*`, `.` --> `\.` and so on.

Comment: I am not able to write a clean code with escape a bunch of meta-characters , It's giving error as "Undefined variable: pat" can you plz help out.